# QLabel crashes when rendering \t\n?

Tags: qt

I'm running Qt 4.6.3 on embedded Linux.

All of my `QLabel` instances crash when the text contains `\t\n`.

I googled for "qlabel \t\n crash" and quite a few people reported similar crashes.

Is "\t\n" something special that I shouldn't use with `QLabel` or is this a bug in QT?

Comment: Never heard about this problem. Could you give us a piece of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known Qt bug of version 4.6.3 [QTBUG-11427](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11427). It was fixed in the version 4.7.1. If it is mandatory to use 4.6.3 it makes sense to avoid such cases.

It looks that the bug is also fixed in Qt 4.6.4. The commit ["Fix possible crash in QTextLayout for glyphless items" 8af2f7b5085ee56d289584bddbccc8dead04b9d1](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/commit/?h=4.6&id=8af2f7b5085ee56d289584bddbccc8dead04b9d1)